# Public static control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Does anyone have any idea how I could create, let's say, a `public static RichTextBox` in XAML? It's easy if I declare it in code:

```
      public static RichTextBox r;
```

But how about in XAML? It seems like it should be possible but I couldn't manage to do it with:

```
    <RichTextBox x:Name="convBox" Margin="29.333,26,39.333,95" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Is it possible to make it public and static from XAML?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it as a resource in App.xaml. Static variables are really just global variables and resources defined in App.xaml are really just globals also. There are various differences of course. I'm not sure what this would achieve with a rich text box but does answer your question in a fashion.

Comment: How to add App.xaml file in my WinForm based app,all I can do is to add UserControl related xaml.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, as explained by @MikeKulls' answer. Here's the actual implementation:

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <RichTextBox x:Key="convBox" Margin="29.333,26,39.333,95" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

ViewUsingStaticControl.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource convBox}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Important note:**
As mentioned in @H.B.'s answer, elements can only have one parent. The result of using a static control in this fashion is that if the static control is currently being displayed in one view and a different view that includes the static control is then displayed, the static control will be removed from the first view and added to the most recent view loaded.

Answer (score 2):

No, this should **not** be possible because it would be shared accross all instances of that control/window/etc, which cannot be done with one instance as it would have multiple parents.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The only option you have is `FieldModifier` which can make the control public, not also static.

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="convBox" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="29.333,26,39.333,95" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```